# Using a Python dictionary to edit image

Tags: python, image, dictionary

First i am a beginner of Programming so i may have stupid questions ;)

I created a dictionary like this:

```
cell = {(1,2):200,(1,2):200,(1,2):200,(1,2):200,...}
```

and now i used Image to create a new image. the idea is to use cell.keys() for example (1,2) to access the pixels coordinates of the image and change the value to the value of the key. how could i do that? I tried this "unpacking", with no success other than "invalid syntax"

```
cell = {}
for i in range (255):
    for k in range (255):
        cell.update({(i,k):random.randrange(1,150,2)})

img = Image.new('RGB',(255,255), 'WHITE')
pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map

for k in cell.keys():  
    pixels[*k] = (*k, cell[k]) # here I get the invalid syntax at '*k'
```

Comment: "Invalid syntax" at which line?

Comment: the last line at "*k"

Comment: @LutzHorn probably on fourth line: `{(i,k):random.randrange(1,150,2)}`

Comment: @utdemir: that's just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters; my bad, I didn't think that was a simple literal dict, thought that was some kind of dict comprehension attempt. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `k` as the key:

```
pixels[k] = k + (cell[k],)
```

You have a RGB image, so you need a tuple with 3 values. `k` is a tuple with *two* values, so I am guessing you want a `(i, j, random_value)` tuple for the pixel value.

`*k` only works in function signatures, calls, and (in Python 3) for tuple assignments. It has no special meaning in indexing or creating a tuple literal.

Note that using `dict.update()` with a one-element dictionary is.. inefficient. Just use item assignment instead:

```
cell = {}
for i in range(255):
    for k in range(255):
        cell[(i,k)] =  random.randrange(1,150,2)
```

A dictionary is not the best data storage format for a dense matrix however; better use a nested list:

```
cell = [[random.randrange(1,150,2) for _ in range(255)] for _ in range(255)]
```

and address this with:

```
for i, row in enumerate(cell):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        pixels[i, j] = (i, j, value)
```

Comment: Ah! thank you! putting    pixels[k] = (k, cell[k],) gives this error: TypeError: function takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: @user3759978: the value is *not*  a nested tuple. It depends on the image mode what the value should be set to.

Comment: @user3759978: I see you have a `'RGB'` (3 band) image, so you need to use a tuple with three values here.

Comment: i have to stick to the dictionary, because it is a requirement of my supervisor ;)

Comment: Good idea^^ And yes, your answer was very helpful ;)